# Rails bower doesn't compile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, assets, bower

I have my rails solution using Bower to manage my frontend libraries.
I followed [this tutorial](http://start.jcolemorrison.com/angularjs-rails-4-1-and-ui-router-tutorial/) to setup it.
It's working, but when I try to precompile this, it blows up with the following error:

```
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile
rake aborted!
ExecJS::ProgramError: Unexpected token: eof (undefined) (line: 46, col: 0, pos: 1406)

Error
    at new JS_Parse_Error (/tmp/execjs20140911-20410-llghcjjs:2357:10623)
    at js_error (/tmp/execjs20140911-20410-llghcjjs:2357:10842)
    at croak (/tmp/execjs20140911-20410-llghcjjs:2357:19067)
    at token_error (/tmp/execjs20140911-20410-llghcjjs:2357:19204)
    at unexpected (/tmp/execjs20140911-20410-llghcjjs:2357:19292)
    at block_ (/tmp/execjs20140911-20410-llghcjjs:2357:24537)
    at ctor.body (/tmp/execjs20140911-20410-llghcjjs:2357:24191)
    at function_ (/tmp/execjs20140911-20410-llghcjjs:2357:24256)
    at expr_atom (/tmp/execjs20140911-20410-llghcjjs:2357:27308)
    at maybe_unary (/tmp/execjs20140911-20410-llghcjjs:2357:29977)
  (in /home/augustopedraza/Documents/Projects/BuscoHogar/landing-page/vendor/assets/bower_components/jquery/src/intro.js)
```

Any idea how to fix it?

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: what's at line `46` of `/home/augustopedraza/Documents/Projects/BuscoHogar/landing-page/vendor/assets/bower_components/jquery/src/intro.js`?

Comment: That is the jQuery code that Bower downloaded after run:
`rake bower:install`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.. I figured out it was because of the compression of the assets generally.. So a temporary fix will be commenting this line in config/environments/production.rb:

```
config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier
```

I currently don't know if uglifier itself causes the error after compressing the JS files or if the JS has something wrong. I'm currently exploring other alternatives for js compression to see if it'll work.. P.S. I'm also using bower components so maybe bower + uglifier causes the error

Comment: Yes, commenting that line worked form me, have you found a proper fix or an alternative uglifier?

Answer (score -1):

I was able to fix this by editing the file intro.js  The line producing the error is:

```
 }(typeof window !== "undefined" ? window : this, function( window, noGlobal ){
```

change it to

```
}(typeof window !== "undefined" ? window : this, function( window, noGlobal ){}));
```

You will probably now get the error for outro.js, which only contains the missing

```
}));
```

Just delete it out and everything should compile.  I haven't extensively tested it but I haven't noticed anything with jquery breaking because of these changes.

Comment: This is a bad idea, as intro.js and outro.js are wrappers and not standalone js files, doing this should break something. source: https://github.com/jquery/jquery/issues/2106